# Class object initialization

Tags: c++, oop

Hi I know this seems like a really dumb question and honestly I'm lost on what is causing this object error and could really use some help.

I have this `class` here :

```
class PriorityQueue {
  public:
    PriorityQueue(std::size_t max_nodes);
    void insert(Key k);
    void insert(KeyValuePair kv);
    KeyValuePair min();
    KeyValuePair removeMin();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    size_t size() const;
    nlohmann::json JSON() const;

  private:
    void heapifyUp(size_t i);
    void heapifyDown(size_t i);
    void removeNode(size_t i);
    Key getKey(size_t i);

    std::vector<KeyValuePair>   nodes_;
    size_t                      max_size_;
    size_t                      size_;

    const static size_t         ROOT = 1;
};  // class PriorityQueue

#endif  // _PRIORITYQUEUE_H_
```

Everything is properly defined in the corresponding cpp file for it.
Now I'm trying to call it in a separate file that includes both as a header.

```
#include "priorityqueue.cpp"
#include "priorityqueue.h"
```

But in my `main()` function when I try to call the class to an object like

```
PriorityQueue m;
```

I get the error

```
no matching function for call to ‘PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue()’
PriorityQueue m;
```

I know this seems like a really basic C++ question but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `#include "priorityqueue.cpp"` - This is only going to cause you grief down the line. Get out of the habit. It's better to work *with* the way C++ is compiled and linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the first, remove `#include "priorityqueue.cpp"` and just use of `#include "priorityqueue.h"`

Because your constructor has a parameter :

```
PriorityQueue(std::size_t max_nodes);
```

So, you should set `max_nodes` when you creating an object :

```
PriorityQueue m(10);
```

But you can also implement a default constructor with a default parameter :

In the header file

```
// In this approach you can use a default constructor
// Declaration
class PriorityQueue {
  public:
    PriorityQueue(std::size_t max_nodes = 10);
    ...
};
```

In the cpp file

```
// Implementation
PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue(std::size_t max_nodes)
{
    max_size_ = max_nodes;
 // initialize members
}
```

Then you can create instance like bellow :

```
PriorityQueue m;      // max_size_ will be set to default value (10)
PriorityQueue n(7);   // max_size_ will be set to 7
```

[***Try online***](http://cpp.sh/3627c)

Comment: Yep, now I realize it lol. This was extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: To avoid redundancy, you can also set a default argument for `max_nodes` parameter as follows: `PriorityQueue(std::size_t max_nodes = /* default */ ) ...`. Then, it will be a default constructor as well.

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi You didn't understand my comment. You still have 2 distinct constructors. My point was that both these constructors may be easily merged into one. BTW, it's better to initialize member variables in a constructor initializer list than in constructor's body.

Comment: It's worth stressing however that the default argument better appear at the class declaration to be of any use.